# Setup example.com/subdirectory/ in Nginx

Tags: nginx

Is there any possibility to setup Nginx for this: I want `www.example.com/subdirectory/` and that `/subdirectory/` take files from `/var/www/site/web/subdirectory`

My site is working, I just want to setup that `/subdirectory/` route.

Is that somehow possible?

My Nginx configuration is:

```
server {
    server_name server;
    root /var/www/site/web;

    location / {
        # try to serve file directly, fallback to app.php
        try_files $uri /app.php$is_args$args;
    }
    # DEV
    # This rule should only be placed on your development environment
    # In production, don't include this and don't deploy app_dev.php or config.php
    location ~ ^/(app_dev|config)\.php(/|$) {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
        include fastcgi_params;
        # When you are using symlinks to link the document root to the
        # current version of your application, you should pass the real
        # application path instead of the path to the symlink to PHP
        # FPM.
        # Otherwise, PHP's OPcache may not properly detect changes to
        # your PHP files (see https://github.com/zendtech/ZendOptimizerPlus/issues/126
        # for more information).
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root;
    }

    # PROD
    location ~ ^/app\.php(/|$) {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
        include fastcgi_params;
        # When you are using symlinks to link the document root to the
        # current version of your application, you should pass the real
        # application path instead of the path to the symlink to PHP
        # FPM.
        # Otherwise, PHP's OPcache may not properly detect changes to
        # your PHP files (see https://github.com/zendtech/ZendOptimizerPlus/issues/126
        # for more information).
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root;
        # Prevents URIs that include the front controller. This will 404:
        # http://domain.tld/app.php/some-path
        # Remove the internal directive to allow URIs like this
        internal;
    }

   location /subdirectory {
    alias /var/www/site/web/subdir/;
}

    # return 404 for all other php files not matching the front controller
    # this prevents access to other php files you don't want to be accessible.
    location ~ \.php$ {
      return 404;
    }

    error_log /var/log/nginx/sm_error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/sm_access.log;
```

I have a problem with 404 error, I dont know why. I have `www-data` user on that subdirectory.

```
location /subdirectory {
    root /var/www/site/web/subdirectory;
    try_files $uri /administration.php$is_args$args;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root;

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the following into `server` section:

```
location /subdirectory {
   root /var/www/site/web;
}
```

Or other solution which is working when `/url_directory` and `/local_directory` doesn't equal:

```
location /subdirectory {
   alias /var/www/site/web/subdirectory;
}
```

See more on [nginx/location](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location), [nginx/root](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#root) and [nginx/alias](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#alias).

Comment: Thanks, but now I have 403 forbiden error, even with 777 or www-data recusively on that subdirectory. A used alias solution.

Comment: Do you have `index index.html index.html index.php` or similar? Or maybe `autoindex on`?

Comment: I have to setup special index for that location too?

Comment: Do you've in the `server` section? Can you post full `nginx.conf`?

Comment: Added to main post full vhost configuration its Symfony 3

Comment: You don't have `index` so you should add it into `location` (or a `try_files`). And if you want access `php`-files in `/var/www/site/web/subdirectory` you should add a "`php`-handler" (`fastcgi...`).

Comment: Edited my main post, can you once again help me please?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121536/discussion-between-delirium-and-uzsolt).